# Why is my object getting nulled for On Post when is filled in OnGet

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a class with the following (reduced for brevity)

```
 [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
        public List<Expenditure> ListExpendituresOver90Days { get; set; }

public async Task OnGetAsync(int projectId, string ExpenditureFilter, string personnelNo)
        {
           ListExpendituresOver90Days = ExpendituresList.ToList();
         }

 public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostButtonAsync()
        {
           return page();
         }
```

and the cshtml with:

```
@model WorkInProgress.Pages.Expenditures
<thead>
<tr>
    <th class = text-start>Task Number</th>
    <th class = text-start>Expenditure Type</th>
    <th class = text-end>Item Date</th>
    <th class = text-end>Billable</th>
    <th class = text-end>Vendor Id</th>
    <th class = text-start>Vendor Name</th>
    <th class = text-end>Revenue Amount</th>
    <th class = text-end>Comments</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

@for (var x = 0; x < @Model.ListExpendituresOver90Days.Count(); x++)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ListExpendituresOver90Days[x].ExpenditureItemId)
    <tr>
        
        <td class=text-start>@Model.ListExpendituresOver90Days[x].TaskNumber</td>
        <td class=text-start>@Model.ListExpendituresOver90Days[x].ExpenditureType</td>
        <td class=text-end>@Model.ListExpendituresOver90Days[x].ExpenditureItemDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")</td>
        <td class=text-end>@Model.ListExpendituresOver90Days[x].BillableFlag</td>
        <td class=text-end>@Model.ListExpendituresOver90Days[x].VendorId</td>
        <td class=text-start>@Model.ListExpendituresOver90Days[x].SupplierName</td>
        <td class=text-end>@Model.ListExpendituresOver90Days[x].ProjFuncRevenueAmount</td>
        <td class=text-end>
            <textarea class="form-control" form="MainForm" asp-for="@Model.ListExpendituresOver90Days[x].ExpenditureComment"  rows="1"></textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</tbody>

<div class="form-control">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" asp-page-handler="Button">Save</button>
</div>
```

when the page loads, the data gets filled for all columns, and the object "ListExpendituresOver90Days" contains the enumerator with all properties populated as it should:

[image]

however when I click on the "Save" button and this calls the onPost method, the object comes back empty, except for the value inserted in the comment TextArea:

[image]

I have tried putting only the needed to replicate my error, but in case is useful, I'm putting here a GIST with all the code that I have for this screen:

https://gist.github.com/gasguirre/18a19d07cf1c14db2aafb539253461f9

the section I'm using for the For loop that is not working properly is in "_Over90DaysExpenditureLayout.cshtml"

Comment: You can change your `td` tag like this:`<td class=text-start><input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.ListExpendituresOver90Days[x].TaskNumber" />@Model.ListExpendituresOver90Days[x].TaskNumber</td>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is how the web works - it is stateless by design. When you make a GET request, your PageModel is instantiated and the `OnGet` method is invoked. Once the HTML response has been sent, the PageModel instance is destroyed along with all its state. When you make a POST request, a new instance of the PageModel is created and the `OnPostButtonAsync` method is invoked. The `OnGetAsync` method is not - by convention it is only invoked for GET requests. If you want all values in each `Expenditure` to be reconstituted in the POST request handler, you can create hidden fields for each one.

Comment: this and the comment from @Chen were the solution, thank you.